.NET Core 8.0 RegularExpression attribute always shows default error message
This is my controller action method, I am trying to validate a string using Regular Expressions, the condition works but it always shows the default error message instead of the custom message.
[HttpGet("{number}")] public async Task<IActionResult> GetDetails( [FromRoute][RegularExpression(@"^\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}-\d{5}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid format for number.")] string number)
Expecting: It should show the custom error message which is binded with the property ErrorMessage of RegularExpression attribute

[RegularExpression] shall be added to model properties, but not directly to parameters in action methods behind [FromRoute]. So that I'm afraid you could try this, and it worked well in my side.
public class RegController : Controller
{
    [Route("reg/index/{number}")]
    public IActionResult Index([FromRoute] RouteModel mod)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        return Ok("success");
    }
}

public class RouteModel
{
    [RegularExpression("^\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}-\\d{5}$", ErrorMessage = "Custom Invalid format for number.")]
    public string number { get; set; }
}



I was following this approach already and it's working fine, so thought to use the same in the Action methods itself. It works anyways but not showing the custom error message.
Thanks for the response, I'll use the suggested way meanwhile.

Thanks a lot for your confirmation. Can I understand this question has ended now?

Yes we can close it for now!
